# Data distribution not showing in power bi though the models have relationship

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I have two models: `Data` and `Product Master`.
Their relationship is defined as joining by Category Name:

[image]

I have written measure as:

```
2. Total sales = SUM(Data[Sales Amount])
```

It appears as:

[image]

Then I checked:

[image]

It shows:

[image]

Why is not the distribution of `category name` and `Name` and showing in table?

Then after If , I uncheck measure    `2. Total sales` then it will show:

[image]

Why is the distribution of  of `category name` and `Name` not showing according to total sales?

Comment: Check your relationship. Are you sure that you connect the correct columns? Data Type is that same? Any white space on one side of the relationship? "Tshirt " instead of "Tshirt"

Comment: Please show some sample about the two table, perhaps you link relationship on the wrong column, therefore no name is display

Comment: yes, it was trim issue. please answer it separately. so i can tick right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your relationship. Are you sure that you connect the correct columns? Data Type is that same? Any white space on one side of the relationship? "Tshirt " instead of "Tshirt"